# Gnome 3 notification doesn't appear While vlc is runnig

Tags: fedora, gnome3, vlc

I am using Gnome3 on Fedora 15.

One of the good features of Gnome3 is Notifications from empathy will appear while you are watching a movie in the movie player and you can reply without changing the focus. This is working with totem movie player, but not with VLC.

Actually the notification will have the top Z-index but it fails to get the top position with VLC.

Comment: Hopefully somebody can provide a work-around for you here, but this is something you should mention to the VLC developers either on a list or a bug-tracker. They are probably setting some window property that makes the player window too agressive. Perhaps they can detect Gnome3 and play nicer.

Comment: thnx fr the info, I'll try to post the bug at VLC

Answer (score 1):

Most applications need to be modified by their developers to play nicely with the new GNOME Shell messaging and notifications paradigm.  Some applications have been modified, most have not.